# NSMutableArray does not save objects retrieved from the database (core data)

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I have a very strange problem, and it's driving me crazy.

The senario is an app with local database (core data), which receives updates from a server, I'll post here only the most relevant code.

This code below is called before starting to download the update. The purpose of it is to save all records to the table IMAGES if you have problems while downloading the data to be restored to the table.

```
//Passa contexto do ManagedObjectContext do appDelegate
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    if ([SQLite count:managedObjectContext :@"IMAGENS"]!=0) {
        NSMutableArray *fetchResults = [SQLite select:managedObjectContext :@"IMAGENS" :NULL];

        oldImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fetchResults copy]];

        NSLog(@"SALVOU OLD IMAGENS");

    }
```

I checked that trough test data is actually saved, so far no problem.

This other trexo code is called if you have problems during the download and purpose of it is to clean the table and insert IMAGES objects that were saved in the method I posted just above ..

```
   -(void)recoverImages{
        if ([oldImages count]!=0) {
            NSMutableArray *fetchResults = [SQLite select:managedObjectContext :@"IMAGENS" :NULL];

                //Se tiver Objetos salvos na tabela, todos serão apagados
                if ([fetchResults count]!=0) {
                    for (Imagens *imagem in fetchResults) {
                        //Deleta objeto
                        [SQLite deletarImagem:managedObjectContext :imagem];
                        NSLog(@"deletou imagens no recover!");
                    }


                    for (Imagens *img in oldImages) {
                        Imagens *imagem = (Imagens *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IMAGENS" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

                       [imagem setCategoria:img.categoria];
                       [imagem setTitulo:img.titulo];
                       [imagem setDescricao:img.descricao];
                       [imagem setImagem:img.imagem];

                        NSError *er;
                        if(![managedObjectContext save:&er]){
                            NSLog(@"Houve um erro muito grave ao salvar imagem old");
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"\nTítulo:%@",imagem.titulo);
                            NSLog(@"\nDescrição:%@",imagem.descricao);
                            NSLog(@"\nCategoria:%@",imagem.categoria);
                        }

                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

The NSMutableArray is not void because it runs in the first test and also enters the second case, however, for this output

```
NSLog (@ "\ nTítulo:% @" imagem.titulo);
NSLog (@ "\ nDescription:% @" imagem.descricao);
NSLog (@ "\ nCategoria:% @" imagem.categoria);
```

I get Null for all objects, it is as if the objects were no longer her.

The most common errors for this is not initialize the NSMutableArray, but as you can see it is initialized.

I've done testing saving the data on a NSUserDefaults out instead of a var for instance, but there was the same problem.

Forgot to mention, the NSMutableArray oldImages is a instance variable.

Can you see any problems?

NOTE: The class SQLite is a class I wrote containing some functions to interact with the database more simplified.

Comment: There is definitely a problem at `imagem = img;` - You *overwrite* the pointer to the newly created object with a different pointer. I don't understand your logic yet, but perhaps you have to copy the properties of `img` to `imagem` instead.

Comment: Actually also already tried this code
  [image setCategoria: img.categoria];
  [image setTitulo: img.titulo];
  [image setDescricao: img.descricao];
  [image set picture: img.imagem];

But I get null in debug output

Comment: Ditch your `SQLite` class and use the standard core data methods.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, but anyway not helped me ... And SQLite class I wrote works perfectly, actually inside it has the standard methods, is just a more simple to use, instead of using 10 lines of code to recurerar data, use only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough time lost by cause of this problem, I decided to save the NSMutableArray instead of object (Images *), save a NSDictionaty with your information as follows:

```
oldImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Imagens *img in fetchResults) {
            if (img) {
                NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:img.categoria,@"categoria",img.titulo,@"titulo",img.descricao,@"descricao",img.imagem,@"imagem", nil];

                [oldImages addObject:dic];

            }
        }
```

and then to recover:

```
 for (NSDictionary *img in oldImages) {
                Imagens *imagem = (Imagens *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IMAGENS" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

                [imagem setCategoria:[img valueForKey:@"categoria"]];
                [imagem setTitulo:[img valueForKey:@"titulo"]];
                [imagem setDescricao:[img valueForKey:@"descricao"]];
                [imagem setImagem:[img valueForKey:@"imagem"]];

                NSError *er;
                if(![managedObjectContext save:&er]){
                    NSLog(@"Houve um erro muito grave ao salvar imagem old");
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"\nTítulo:%@",[img valueForKey:@"titulo"]);
                    NSLog(@"\nDescrição:%@",[img valueForKey:@"descricao"]);
                    NSLog(@"\nCategoria:%@",[img valueForKey:@"categoria"]);
                }

            }
```

for some reason does not save my NSMutableArray objects (Images *), does it have something to do with inheriting class NSManageObject?